# Hibernate deletes relations in a @ManyToMany relationsship with lazy loading

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I've got an issue with hibernate deleting my relations between two objects. First one is:

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name="A")
    public class A extends AbstractBO{

        private List<B> b;

        @Override
        @Id
        public String getId(){
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
        }

        @ManyToMany(targetEntity=B.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(name="A_B", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="A_id")},inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="B_id")})
        public List<B> getBs() {
            return b;
        }

        public void setBs(List<B> b) {
        this.b = b;
        }
    }
```

And second one:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="B")
public class B extends AbstractBO {

    private List<A> a;

    @Override
    @Id
    public String getId(){
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @ManyToMany(targetEntity=A.class, fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="b")
    public List<A> getAs() {
        return a;
    }

    public void setAs(List<A> a) {
        this.a = a;
        }
}
```

My hibernate.cfg.xml is:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">****</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.release_mode">auto</property>
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics">false</property>

    <property name="transaction.factory_class">
      org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory
    </property>
    <property name="hibernate.cache.provider_class">
      org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider
    </property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">2</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>

    <mapping class="de.test.A"/>
    <mapping class="de.test.B"/>    

  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

So far, everything works fine. It's possible to save, update, delete and load all objects persisted in the DB and all of their children. If I'm loading an object of type `A`, calling `getBs()` at the frontend included, I get the right one and all of its childs displayed. But hibernate does "Hibernate: delete from A_B where B_id=?" immediately after the SELECT statement. This deletes all relations between the object and its children. 
If I change `FetchType` of `B` to "EAGER", everything works fine. It seems, that hibernate removes tue to the fact, that `getAs()` of the children objects isn't called.

I also tried changing `getAs()` of class `B` to:

```
@JoinTable(name="A_B", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="B_id")}, inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name="A_id")})
    public List<A> getAs() {[...]
```

By the way, I'm using:

- hibernate 4.2.4 final
- JSF 2.0
- JPA 2.0

I've read many related articles and tried different suggestions with Cascade etc. Also I thought about calling `getAs()` in the constructor of `B`, but all these things doesn't solve my problem.

While debbuging my application I added one row to the getter of class `B`:

```
public List<A> getAs() {
    if(a!=null) a.size();
    return a;
}
```

Calling `a.size()` doesn't change anything. So I was bewildered as everything works suddenly. So as a conclusion, my application works now with this "fix". But I would be grateful if anybody could give me a more common solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have `hibernate.enable_lazy_load_no_trans` enabled and the bug is still open I would guess that you are a victim of [HHH-7971](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7971). I can not give you a proper solution for this, if the behaviour is a result of this bug you can just use a workaround to fix it.

I guess that `a.size()` fixes this is, because the Hibernate proxy gets initialized in that moment. So it would be more appropriate to use `Hibernate.initialize(a)`. Also I would not do that in the getter, but at the place where you call the getter.

Comment: Why do you recommend the use of Hibernate.initialize(a) ? I will try your suggestion and will update this question afterwards.

Comment: On the one hand it is much more readable and everybody knows whats going on when he reads the line and on the other hand you do not have to do the `null` check.

Comment: Unfortunately Hibernate.initialize(a) doesn't solve that issue. I implemented it in the getter, because my application does call that getter directly from the frontend. While running your suggestion, relations got deleted again.

Comment: Btw. I've recognized, that if hibernate deletes all realtions after SELECT and I'm going to call saveOrUpdate on the parent object, all relations are insert again.

Comment: Ah I'm sorry, `Hibernate.initialize` does not initialize `a` itself, but it initializes each element of `a` (which are proxies). So I think the most appropriate way would be the call of `a.size()`. Deleting and reinserting after each select is not a good way of solving this issue.

Comment: I agree, deleting and reinserting would not be a solution. It should just be an other hint, which may help finding the problem. Cause this means hibernate does not delete the relations due to an empty collection accessed by the getter. If it is possible to resinsert the realtions again, all objects of class `B` have to be anywhere. However, can you explain what happens while calling `a.size()` in `getAs()`?

Comment: The proxy Hibernate uses for `List`s usually is the `PersistentBag`. So when you call `a.size()` in `getAs()` the proxy of the `List` gets initialized and so the elements (respectively the proxies of the elements) of the List will get loaded. Have a look at the Hibernate core documentation for more information http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching-initialization.

Comment: DO NOT USE THIS FEATURE. It is broken and you will loose your data.